# Pagination - loading overrides the previous state

Tags: api, react-native, pagination, state, reducers

I am facing an issue regarding the pagination in my application. The users have a list of transactions, so we decided to create a slow load in the Section List. 
The api works correctly and fetches the data, however. every time I get new data, the previous state is overwritten by the new state.

This is my reducer:

```js
export default function(state = {}, { type, sequence, payload } = {}) {
  switch (type) {
    case TRANSACTIONS.FETCH: //used when fetching the first page
      return sequence === REQUEST.SUCCESS ? payload : state;

    case TRANSACTIONS.FETCH_MORE: { //fetching next pages
      return sequence === REQUEST.SUCCESS ? { ...state, ...payload } : state;
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

The transactions data looks like this:

```
transactions: {
data: {},
links:{},
meta:{}
}
```

[payload Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfgV6.png)
[state Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vzfA.png)

Comment: Please show your payload object, and your state too.

Comment: @Anarno see the screenshots attached in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case is more complex than you expected :( . Your `data` object in the state is an array. When you push your payload state, you replace the complete `data` object whit the new `data` object. You need a better reducer structure for this screnario:

```js
export default function(state = {}, { type, sequence, payload } = {}) {
  switch (type) {
    case TRANSACTIONS.FETCH: //used when fetching the first page
      return sequence === REQUEST.SUCCESS ? payload : state;

    case TRANSACTIONS.FETCH_MORE: { //fetching next pages
      return sequence === REQUEST.SUCCESS ? {
        ...state,
        data: [...state.data, ...payload.data], // <--- concat the data arrays IMMUTABLE way.
        links: payload.links, // <--- it don`t know what you want here, replace or modify, please share more about this.
        meta: payload.meta // <--- here too.
      } : state;
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: This approach works. Thank you! I thought that my case is more complicated, but I did not know how to make it work. I don't need to load the links and meta again, the initial state from the TRANSACTIONS.FETCH is enough for me, so I only used: { ...state,
        data: [...state.data, ...payload.data]}